# Error undefined reference to `dladdr' in Visual Studio 2017 cross-platform

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code, linker-errors

I am writing small program using 3rd party library. 3rd party library is placed in Linux machine. From visual studio 2017 using crossplatform i am running my small code with help of 3rd party library(.so files). path everything mentioned properly and vs2017 able to find .so files but facing below issues.

```
Error       undefined reference to `dladdr'
Error       undefined reference to `dlopen'
```

Note: In linker ->Report Unsolved Symbol Reference ->Yes (-Wl,--no-undefined)
but still facing that errors. Any linkers settings need to be added?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `--version` option at all, since all it will do is cause the tool to print version information and exit. Nothing will be built. As for the other errors, have you tried reading documentation about them? Does the documentation mentioned any specific library you need to link with?

Comment: You should show the link command you are using. See the [`dlopen(3)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [`dladdr(3)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html). Pay attention to the link library.

Comment: Could you please clarify if you are using Visual Studio (title of the question) or Visual Studio Code (tag)?

Comment: @Bob - I added the VSCode tag due to Linux. It may have been a mistake. You might want to look at the question history. Things may make better sense.